# Data width always gets style of 0px

Tags: laravel, datatables

Using Yajra with Bootstrap 4, I try to display the table like so:

```
<div class="row col-12 table-responsive">
    {{  $myDataTable->table()  }}
</div>
```

and set the parameters:

```
->parameters([
    'processing' => false,
    'serverSide' => true,
    "paging" => false,
    'buttons' => [],
```

But my table does not spread across the entire 12 columns, it gets very squeezed with style of 0px on the table tag: `<table class="dataTable" style="0px">`

How to get the table spread to the 12 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you have set everything up correctly? For starters, try using the following for your table classes:

```
<table class="datatable-table table">
```

Then make sure that you have imported the proper stylesheet/scripts through CDNs or by throwing them in your project. You'll at least need "datatables.css" and "datatables.js".

Comment: But the table element is being created automatically by DataTables, how can I add it via the code?

Comment: How exactly did you set up your Yajara table? I would advise starting over and perhaps following [this tutorial article](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-datatables-example/) to make sure everything is in order. Because you should be able to access your table tag from your blade.